# Node.JS - Server to server data transfer memory leak and slow network speeds

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

Ok, this is not going to be easy to explain, but I'll give it my best..

We have a file sharing solution serving (small images to big 3d drawings/videos(++5-10GB) running on a strange network setup (IT Security request).

We have the internal zone (LAN) with a NODE.js server:

1. Backend ( Windows Server 2008 2x2.60Ghz 16GB Ram and disk transfer speed of up till 122 MB/S read). 0.8.22 (Some MSNodeSQL stuff so cant use the newer Node versions.. Converting to TDS now

We then have a external zone ( DMZ ) where the proxy and web-server lives.

1. Proxy ( Ubuntu 12.10 1x2.60Ghz 32GB Ram rest is same as above ) node 0.8.22. Proxy is the only server that can access the LAN, but there is only one port open and it has to be initilized by the backend..
2. Web ( Windows Server 2008 8x2.60Ghz 16GB ram and rest is same as above ) node 0.10.12

So, we need to transfer a file to the client connected to the web-server.
The library I've used now is BinaryJS witch works good, but we have a extreamly slow transfer speed of about 12MB/s and this drops when new clients are connecting (usuall arround 4-6MB/s).

Request flow:
- Client (browser) -> Web-Server over https

- Web-Server -> Proxy over BinaryJS
- Proxy -> Backend over BinaryJS CreateStream.
- Backend -> Proxy with a stream object that are piped to the web-server socket.
- Proxy to Web-Server via pipe ( the original request )
- Web-Server -> Client (Browser) binaryStream.pipe(res) where res is the ExpressJS response.

From testing it seems like we loose 50% of the transfer speed for each server (backend, proxy, web) we go through and i cant figure out why.. We have enough bandwidth and disk speed to get full speed of the Gigabit connected clients. Also the memory and CPU are not working that hard.

Code:
Backend (BASIC) - DB Query's of filepath etc is removed :

```
client = BinaryClient('wss://'+config.proxy+':'+config.port+'/binary');
client.on('stream', function(msgStream, msgMeta){
       console.log("Got stream with meta: ", msgMeta);
            var stream = require('fs').createReadStream(msgMeta.filepath);
                stream.pipe(msgStream);
                    msgStream.on('error', function(e){
                        console.log("Bin stream failed: ", e);
                    });
                    msgStream.on('close', function(){
                        console.log("Stream closed")
                    });
                    stream.on('end', function(){
                        console.log("Ending file stream of file: ", msgMeta.meta.itemID);
                        msgStream.end();

                    });
                }
            })
```

Proxy:

```
var binServer = BinaryServer({port:8001});
binServer.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
        if(meta.register == true){
            if(meta.who == "master"){
                config.masterBinary = client;
            } 
        } else {
            // Its a stream request.
            if(meta.what == "GET"){
                config.masterBinary.createStream(meta).pipe(stream).on('close', function(){
                    console.log("CLOSED");
                }).on('end', function(){
                    console.log("ENDED");
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Web-Server:

```
    client = binaryClient('wss://'+config.proxy+':'+config.port+'/binary');
client.on('open', function(){
    ready = true;
})
client.on('close', function(){
    ready = false;
})
exports.get = function(file, res, cb){
// This get called from the Express request.. Client will wait for the stream to start
console.log("Sending request to backend: ", file);
if(file.itemID || file.requestID){
    client.createStream({filepath:"C:/SomePathToAFile", register:false,     what:"GET"}).pipe(res);
} else {
    cb("Parameter not present", false);
}
}
```

I've been wondering if is should try to write my own TCP-server and clients to better fit what we are trying to do.. Unfortunate I'm quite new to Node and have not figure out how to implement the EventEmitter into TCP so I can send data with meta for identification..

Is there a better way or have I completly missunderstood the BinaryJS server?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you even do that with express? (The streaming stuff?) I thought express didn't really support streams which is why many people have built alternative frameworks. Not sure :-/

Comment: binaryjs looks like under development. So performance could be an issue. You should ask the developers about your situation. Maybe they can help.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for your comments.. About Express: I've not seen any info about streams not beeing supported with pipe. But what you are saying is interesting so I'm going to invest that furter. Any recommendation instead of Express.js?.. user568109: I read that BinaryJS should be super fast, but I've not seen what they compare it to :-). I'm leaning to writing my own TCP server supporting my server setup instead of relying on something that is not designed for it. I will look arround the BinaryJS site.... Thanks y'all